# how to set CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile IPN

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Step 1.
request with **SetExpressCheckout**

if get success then redirect to paypal

Step 2. curl request with method  **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** With notify url

( getting response only one time )

step 3 if get success response then curl request with method **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**

is my process flow right to create an  intent payment and make a recurring profile ?

and my problem is that i not getting any IPN response when, payment automatically after 1 day.
How to fix this.

Comment: It seems that you have done all the steps (refer to this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/). Are you be able to see the recurring profile created in the 'recurring profile dashboard'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login in to http://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

Create an  Business (merchant account) account and login to http://sandbox.paypal.com/ with your

**Business (merchant account)** and password and click on **profile** **then click **Instant Payment Notification preferences** and set your ipn url